# How to make a function that can convert any string that looks like javascript code to objects?

Tags: javascript, string, object

Being new to javascript, I have a question. Lets, consider a string that looks like this :

```
 var str = "Math.random() > 0.5";
```

Now lets have some javascript :

```
  console.log( turnUp( str ) ); // true or false
```

So, **turnUp()** is just a function I assumed can do something like this :

Without **turnUp()** :

```
 console.log( str );
 // Is equivalent to console.log( "Math.random() > 0.5" );
```

Output :

```
 Math.random() > 0.5
```

With **turnUp()** :

```
 console.log( turnUp( str ) );
 // Is equivalent to console.log( Math.random() > 0.5 );
```

Output :

```
 true
```

Or

Output :

```
 false
```

So, with the help of examples, you might understand what I need ! So, how to make the **turnUp()** function ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please post code of turnup()

Comment: There's `eval()`, which is useful but for various reasons generally considered to be a bad idea in *most* situations. However, it does not "convert" code into "objects"; it evaluates the code with results that vary as the source code varies.

Comment: Thats what I need @Ibnelaiq. I thought it can be done with JSON.parse() but I came to know that such strings can't be parsed with JSON.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq the question is "how to make the **turnUp()** function"; if the OP could post it the question would not have been necessary.

Comment: @Pointy I have heard about that, but I am new to it so can you add an example

Comment: A good habit to get into in cases like this is to search the Internet for "MDN eval". The MDN site is a wiki with a tremendous amount of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval() has many drawbacks so I prefer you to do something like this :

```
 var turnUp = function(str) {
    return Function(' "use strict"; return (' + str + ') ')();
  }
```

Now you can do :

```
 var str = "Math.random() > 0.5";

 console.log( str ); // => Math.random > 0.5
 console.log( turnUp( str ) ); // => true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in javascript which can help you what you're trying to do, but that has it own drawback, Alternatively you can use [`New Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
let str = "Math.random() > 0.5";

let turnUp = new Function('str', `return ${str}`)

console.log(str)
console.log(turnUp(str))
```

Comment: your code works but always alerts saying [object HTMLCollection], on page load, how to stop it ?

Comment: @GamingKing There's no HTML is included neither in question nor in answer, can you post a reproducible example of what you're stating in comment ?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, after all these popups I went thoroughly through the code and found an external script the reason behind. I solved it. Sorry for disturbance

Comment: Note that your `Function` doesn't use the argument in any way, so it can be simply "new Function(`return ${str}`)"

Answer (score 0):

For string:

Use `eval(new string ())` to that string is run like a string no piece of code.Add this in your `turnup()` function.

```
console.log(eval('str'));
```

For Boolean:

```
console.log(str);
```